# vscode installed in other directory gives access denied error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently reinstalled my windows 10
For easy software management I chose to install all my software in the following directories:

- `C:\Program Files\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)`

This meant installing `vscode` and `vscode-insiders` on the `C:\Program Files\`
instead of the default `C:\Users\User\AppData\...\`

However when I am working I get notified with the following popup:
[image: Error, Access is denied]

clicking **> Try again** gives the same popup instantly
clicking **> Cancel installation** removes the popup for a short period
clicking **> Skip this file** keeps giving kind of the same *access is denied* error

Comment: Try running vs code in administrative mode

Comment: Yeah figured that out but I open vscode almost always via open code with: **Open with Code** from right click or command line. I got it working from the right click.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error comes from `vscode` wanting to update in the background.
The `C:\Program Files\` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` are restricted to admin
So running `vscode` in admin mode will fix this issue.

To make sure `vscode` runs in admin mode via this:
[image: Open with Code]

We need to make sure it always runs in admin mode:

Opening the Code.exe with properties (right click and then properties).
Switch to the Compatibility tab and tick the box before:
`Run this program as an administrator`
Remember do this only when you know what you are doing.
Your are giving **admin** / **sudo** powers to `vscode`

[image]

This will fix the popup error.

Comment: This is definitely not a proper way to solve it

Comment: @HirasawaYui I like to invite you for a proper way to solve it

Comment: I really wish I knew how to do that. I've ended up reinstalling my vs code, because running with admin permissions was  not an option for me.

Comment: I personally don't have a big issue with it. I only use this solution on my personal computer and I did manage to have the terminal not run as administrator